# WPF ContextMenu ignores CanExecute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid with elements and a ViewModel behind this view. 
The ViewModel has a RelayCommand, that implements CanExecuteChanged.
There's a Style for DataGridRow that has a ContextMenu, its MenuItems are bound to the RelayCommand and pass the item as a parameter.
Here's the XAML:

```
<ContextMenu  x:Key="CommentMenu" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">       
    <MenuItem Header="Bind to Project" Command="{Binding BindToProjectCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>        

</ContextMenu>
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CommentMenu}" />
</Style>
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
   BindToProjectCommand = new RelayCommand<Comment>(BindToProject, CanBindToProject);
}

public bool CanBindToProject(Comment comment)
{
    var answer = comment != null && comment.ProjectId == null;
    return answer;
}
```

At runtime CanExecuteChanged is called, the correct comment is passed as a parameter, true is returned, but the menu item is still disabled.
The Output window has no binding errors, so the binding is definitely correct, I can see the correct instance coming.
So the questions are:
1. Why does is the result of CanExecute ignored?
2. How to make it work?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: I got a little further on the subject. I was wrong when I stated that I get the correct comment. The fact is: I always get the last comment in the list. So it turns out that the binding gives me a wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the binding of CommandParameter always binds to the last comment in the list. The simplest workaround is to bind SelectedItem to a property in the ViewModel and change the command and the CanBindToProject-method as follows:

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"              
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComment}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"/>

public Comment SelectedComment
public RelayCommand BindToProjectCommand(BindToProject, CanBindToProject)

public bool CanBindToProject()
{
     return SelectedComment != null && SelectedComment.ProjectId == null;
}
```

Comment: Yoy may want to check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670870/wpf-menuitem-commandparameter-binding-set-to-null